# Form to post on website and send push to mobile devices Parse

Tags: javascript, forms, parse-platform, push-notification, web

I'm looking to create an html/javascript based form that posts an article to my website and at the same time will make a push notification through my iOS and future android app. I'd rather do an all in one rather than posting it on the website then doing the push through Parse's website.

I'm just not exactly sure how to go about it if it's even possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible you have to make the HTML form. if your form name is as follows

```
<form id="postArticle">
  <input type="text" it="articleID" name="article">
   <input type="submit"  value="Submit">
</form>
```

you can JS code to submit data and save data in parse and send push notifications to selected devices

```
$("#postArticle").submit(function(e) {   

    var TestObject = Parse.Object.extend("Articles");
    var requestObj = new TestObject();
    requestObj.set('startTime',$("#articleID").val();
    requestObj.save({
        success: function(object) {
            //on success of inserting data to parse we will send notifications to device    
            Parse.Push.send({
              channels: "yourChannel name", 
               deviceType:"ios" , //device types android or iOS
              data: {
                alert: "New Articles submitted",               
                badge: "Increment",
                sound: "default",              
              }
            }, {
              success: function() {
                // Push was successful
                alert("Your request has been send");
              },
              error: function(error) {
                // Handle error
                //console.log(error);
                alert(error.message);
              }
            });

            },
        error:function(error){
              alert(error);
            })

    }
```